# How to require underscore in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

The change log of react-native mentions
https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/04/17/react-native-v0.4.html

> NPM modules compatibility: There are a lot of libraries on NPM that do not depend on node/browser internals that would be really useful in React Native, such as superagent, underscore, ...

But It doesn't work for me.
It is how I install, through package.json

```
# package.json

 "dependencies": {
   "react-native": "*",
   "underscore": "^1.8.3"
   ...
```

And I indeed see it in the npm dependecy

```
# npm ls
├─┬ react-native@0.8.0
|  ...
├── react-native-navbar@0.7.3
└── underscore@1.8.3
```

And it does work for some other react components

It is how I require

```
var _ = require('underscore');
```

But it doesn't work, `_` is undefined

Comment: are you using it in the same file ? can you paste in some code in your question?

Comment: No, the `underscore` library is under the `node_modules` folder, other libraries I used like `react-native-keyboardevents`, `react-native-navbar` all of them are under `node_modules`, too. But they work. I don't know what is the difference between them

Comment: 1. perhaps you are trying to use it from a different file ? a file where you haven't included the `underscore`? 2. maybe try to work with the browser's break points. cmd +d in your simulator and use the sources tab to debug this.

Comment: I had tried it in every files, but it didn't work. I debug this and `require('underscore')` in the console, and it returns `Error: Requiring unknown module "underscore". If you are sure the module is there, try restarting the packager.` And I did (close and npm start again). But it still fail.

Answer (score 47):

If you are using ES6 module (like in ReactNative) the correct way is to use the import statement:

```
import _ from 'lodash'

let text = _.isUndefined(route.rightButtonText) ? 'Default value' : route.rightButtonText;
```

Comment: I used this for importing Underscore in React and it worked.

Comment: I think we should import only neccessary methods like this:

```
  import { flatten, union } from 'lodash';
```

Answer (score 15):

I am using lodash (underscore with more stuff) like this:

1. Add this to the package.json 
   `"lodash": "^3.10.0"`
2. In the component you need just write:
   `var _ = require('lodash')`

And you are set.

Here is more info on lodash if you need [lodash](https://lodash.com/)

Answer (score 8):

To run require successfully in React, this is what I did:

1. Install underscore.

   ```
   npm install underscore
   ```
2. Define a dependency in package.json

   ```
   "dependencies": {
     "react": "^0.13.*",
     "underscore": "^1.8.3"
   }
   ```
3. Define underscore inside the function where you want to use it.

   ```
   render() { 
     let _ = require('underscore')
     let buttonStyle = _.clone(button);
   }
   ```

Comment: Don't quote me on that, but I don't think it's very wise to do a require on the render method.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, the problem is

> I do NOT use it

I just require it and try to test it in console.

When I use it in somewhere, like `_.map([1, 2, 3], function(num){ return num * 3; })` anywhere.

Then I test it in console, it does require the library this time.

I am not sure this is npm require or react-native behavior ?

When you don't use a library, even you require it, it won't be required.